# Property-values database

Tags: database, sqlite, entity-attribute-value, sparql

I have a number of objects, each one have an arbitrary number of shared, and distinct property-value pairs (more specifically: files, and their related properties -such as width, and height values for images, album/artist/length for music files, etc). I'd like to be able to search for objects having specific property/values (such as: by album), group by property, etc.

What kind of database would you suggest for this scenario? Due to modularity (ability to add more properties on-the-fly), as well as the fact of common properties are <20% of all properties, the standard SQL with normalized tables wouldn't really cut it. I have already tried to approach the problem using a "[skinny data model](http://philip.greenspun.com/seia/user-registration-and-management)"; however I have faced with serious scalability issues.

Are there any specialized databases tuned for this scenario (BSD-licensed solutions preferred)? Or any alternative way to tweak standard RDBMs for this?

Comment: Your "skinny data model" is a.k.a. "entity attibute value" or "EAV", in case you want to search for more about it.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for an object having some properties makes me think about a RDF datastore. Have a look a a RDF API (see JENA , sesame, virtuoso ).

Or BerkeleyDB ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) model or [triple](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#section-triples) store. Later can be queried with [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/)

Answer (score 0):

Pierre is right; a triplestore is what you want, and RDF is the standard for that.  SPARQL is the standard language for querying it (a lot like SQL for RDBMS's).

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the databases offered by various Cloud services:

- [Google AppEngine  Datastore](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html)
  (based on Bigtable)
- [Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)
- [Microsoft SDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/dataservices/default.aspx)
- [Apache CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/&ei=8uihSY7UC8bF-QbBnO23Dg&sig2=jt4D-4wXg-pQL9PFZO8vPg&usg=AFQjCNHe5Uo6wBofiBNXHtxRsXkrVqzX4Q)

If Cloud databases aren't an option, BerkelyDB could be a good choice.